# Java Regex - Lookup all matches of {...}

Tags: java, regex, string

I can't find out what's wrong in the following code.
My purpose is to find all occurences of placeholders between *{ }*.

```
String template = "Hello {user}, your  request id is {id}.";
String PH_PATTERN = "\\{\\w+\\}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PH_PATTERN);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(template);

System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());     // >0
System.out.println(matcher.find());           // >true
System.out.println(matcher.matches());        // >false

do {
    System.out.println("Start:" + matcher.start() + ", end:" + matcher.end());
    // Throws: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available
} while (matcher.find());
```

But as you can see this code throws a `No match available exception`.
The regular expression `\{\w+\}` is (seems to be) OK, trying any online parser I see the 2 matches:

Hello **{user}**, your  request id is **{id}**.

```
Group details:
Match # Group index Start index End index   Group content
1       0           6            12         {user}
2       0           34           38         {id}
```

I need to retrieve those group contents, but as you can see there are no groups there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `while` loop instead of a `do-while` loop:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Start:" + matcher.start() + ", end:" + matcher.end());
}
```

Calling `matcher.find()` not only returns `true` if there's another match, but sets the state of the matcher to position it at the match.

A `do-while` loop executes/tests the `while` condition *after* the `do` block is executed. It's obvious how this wouldn't work if you consider what would happen if there were no matches at all.

---

As an aside, you may be reinventing the wheel: See [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html).

Comment: Wow, thank you. That is why even trying to first check matcher.start() I rose an error. find() works more or less like db cursor and needs to be called first. Thanks also for SpEL that is a great hint!